# Is there a command line alternative to the MSMQ management console available in the Computer Management snap-in?

Tags: windows, command-line, msmq

I am using the Computer Management snap-in to inspect the MSMQ status. Specifically, outgoing queues.

I am wondering if there is a command line utility that would let me do so. I.e. running the utility would display all the outgoing queues and their status.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You'd need to write your own app or script (or find one someone else has written).
There's nothing in the product to do it for you.